# Determining ASP.NET Identity's authenticated user within MVC controller JsonResult method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using MVC 5 and have a View that contains a jQuery Ajax call to the controller and retrieve some data. Previously I was unable to make this Ajax GET because the controller is marked `[Authorize]`, so I marked the method as `[AllowAnonymous]`.

At this point I have a need to determine the authenticated user, but `User.Identity` shows `IsAuthenticated = false`. This makes sense, but I am needing to know how I can obtain the user's identity within this method. Here is the method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult GetDesignParams(string countrycode)
{
    ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    if (user != null)
    {
        ... do something ...
    }

    ... do something else ...

    return Json(rules, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Is there a way of obtaining the user's identity within this routine without passing the user id from the client side Ajax GET?

Comment: If you want to know the user's identity, you need to authenticate them - i.e. you need the Authorize attribute or you need to disable anonymous access in some other way.  You say that when you do this you are "unable to make this Ajax GET" - this is the problem you need to solve.  If you can't solve it yourself, provide more details - e.g. how are you doing the authentication?

Comment: I removed the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute and now `Identity.IsAuthorized` equals true. I don't recall why I felt I needed to make my JsonResult methods allow anonymous. Your comment made me revisit this issue and I think qualifies as an answer. If you want to create an answer something to the effect that it's not necessary to make Ajax GET methods in the controller anonymous and/or making them anonymous will cause User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false. Thank you for pointing me in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through bearer tokens in order to make your API-like method secure

See this: [Secure a Web API with Individual Accounts and Local Login](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)